Выборка строк из txt
Подскажите пожалуйста программу или как сделать bat файл для след. задачи.
Есть txt 1 в нем строки в след. формате:
590582793,Елена Сальникова,Илья Сальников,s.ellen@mail.ru,+73519000437,Москва,Шелепихинская набережная,34к2,,,,,55.762819,37.509837,2250,40132735,ios(5.19.1),2021-09-12T23:31:29.000Z,
693597087,Михаил,Михаил Бушков,itsmixa@gmail.com,+73519001175,Москва,Большой Симоновский переулок,2,3,3,83,,55.728216,37.672729,1609,32144052,android (2.62.0),2021-12-23T20:33:01.000Z,
676616358,Владимир,,,+73519002626,Москва,Новодмитровская улица,2к1,,8,72,,55.805113,37.589626,1079,59411655,ios(5.26.1),2021-12-05T03:02:19.000Z,
701593662,Алена,,,+73519007711,рабочий посёлок Заречье,Весенняя улица,2к5,1,9,33,,55.696884,37.400971,3603,30094368,"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) yandex-taxi/650.21.4.185692 YandexEatsKit/1.26.0 Superapp/Eats",2022-01-01T18:32:37.000Z,
592816389,Андрей,,,+73519010233,Москва,Перовская улица,10к2,2,10,144,"В145В8441 - код домофона, звонок в дверь не работает, по звонку выйду на лестничную площадку",55.746522,37.760548,681,73567710,ios(5.19.1),2021-09-15T17:33:14.000Z,

Есть txt 2 в котором указаны улицы:
10-летия Октября
1905 Года
Абельмановская Застава
Абельмановская 
Абрикосовский 
Академика Петровского

и т.д
На выходе нужен файл если улица есть в первом файле она была в финальном файле.
Может есть готов решение?

Вот нашел такой bat
@echo off
for /f %%i in (file2.txt) do (
findstr /c:%%i file1.txt >> file3.txt
)

Но он не работает

По идее на Python с библиотекой Pandas всего несколько строк кода для обработки этого понадобится. Первый файл явно в формате CSV. Только непонятно, почему в первом файле "площадь", "переулок" и т.п., а во втором файле этого нет. Как вы будете сопоставлять из первого файла "улицу Ленина" и "площадь Ленина" со вторым файлом, где будет просто "Ленина", или вам без разницы? Тогда это очень странная задача.

Подходит и площадь Ленина и улица, это не так важно. А без питона можно как-то сделать?

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO!  Согласно правилам Stack Overflow, учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно и указали, что именно вызвало у вас трудности. Пожалуйста, добавьте описание ваших попыток решения задачи и укажите, в чем именно у вас возникли проблемы. Это поможет другим лучше понять вашу ситуацию и предложить более точное решение. как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

На любом(которые умеют работать с файлами) языке программирования эту задачу можно довольно легко решить. Без программирования - excel(там есть функция ВПР). Так же, вы ведь данные откуда то получаете и если это нормальная БД, то такую выборку лучше переложить туда и получать готовый результат

Подскажите пожалуйста программу Excel. Импортируем на два листа. Затем ВПР() на список людей по списку улиц, и сводную по нему - на выходе уникальные общие.

Я надеюсь, ты эти данные выдумал? Не залил в публичный интернет личные реальные данные?
